# How do you create a python script for a Triangular Irregular Network in a stand alone script?

Tags: python, 3d, arcpy

This is my code. I keep getting an error that says my parameters are not valid:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming 
Fundamentals\Final_Project\Contours"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
out_tin = "SampleTin"
in_features = r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming 
Fundamentals\Final_Project\Contours\Site_37_Contours.shp"
height_fields = "None"
sr = arcpy.Describe(in_features).spatialReference
arcpy.CreateTin_3d(out_tin, sr, in_features = in_features, height_field = 
None )
```

My goal is to take a contour data set (line shapefile) and turn it into a TIN.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/262277/115

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be something like?

```
arcpy.CreateTin_3d(out_tin, sr, in_features, Shape.Z <None> )
```

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/create-tin.htm

Comment: That looks like it would be correct, but here is the error I get when I do that:

    arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of <None>.

Comment: give this a try -> arcpy.CreateTin_3d(out_tin, sr, in_features, Shape <None> )